# MYSQL - Select statement ordered by count of matching rows from another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select the most relevant products from a table that match the currently viewed product based on the number of matching product categories.

Sample table A

```
-------------------------------------
| ID | Name | Desc | Price | Active |
-------------------------------------
| 1  | Car  | NR   | $1.00 | Y      |
-------------------------------------
| 2  | Phone| NR   | $2.00 | Y      |
-------------------------------------
| 3  | Pen  | NR   | $1.00 | Y      |
-------------------------------------
| 4  | Book | NR   | $2.00 | Y      |
-------------------------------------
| 5  | Light| NR   | $3.00 | Y      |
-------------------------------------
| 6  | Rock | NR   | $1.00 | Y      |
-------------------------------------
| 7  | Plum | NR   | $1.00 | N      |
-------------------------------------
```

Sample table B

```
---------------
| ID | Cat_ID |
---------------
| 1  | 2      |
---------------
| 1  | 3      |
---------------
| 2  | 1      |
---------------
| 2  | 2      |
---------------
| 2  | 5      |
---------------
| 3  | 3      |
---------------
| 4  | 2      |
---------------
| 4  | 3      |
---------------
| 4  | 6      |
---------------
| 5  | 3      |
---------------
| 6  | 2      |
---------------
| 6  | 3      |
---------------
| 6  | 4      |
---------------
| 7  | 2      |
---------------
| 7  | 3      |
---------------
| 7  | 4      |
---------------
```

When looking at product ID 1 I want to run a query to show the viewer products matching ID's 4 and 6 as other possible options since they share the most category_ID's with number 1 and they are active (Y). In reality, the products might share anywhere from 1 to 30 different categories. It is fine if there are 40 matches, I will use limit 2 to get only two of them.

The issue I am having is that I cannot figure out how to match both the active column from table A and the cat_ID column from Table B against the array of resulting ID's from the Table B query.

The result I want to receive from Table A:

```
--------------------------------
| 4  | Book | NR   | $2.00 | Y |
--------------------------------
| 6  | Rock | NR   | $1.00 | Y |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as variant:

```
SET @ID = 1;
SELECT
    ID,
    count(*) as count_matched
FROM TableB
WHERE 
    ID != @ID
    AND
    CAT_ID IN (SELECT CAT_ID FROM TableB WHERE ID = @ID )
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

**add after comment:**

MySQL do not support LIMIT in subqueries, so You can:

- Handle returned values in application and use it for prepared statements as parameters
- Use temporary tables

> ```
> SET @ID = 1;
> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tt;
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt as
> SELECT
>     ID,
>     count(*) as count_matched
> FROM TableB
> WHERE 
>     ID != @ID
>     AND
>     CAT_ID IN (SELECT CAT_ID FROM TableB WHERE ID = @ID )
> GROUP BY ID
> ORDER BY count(*) DESC
> LIMIT 2;
> SELECT    
>     TableA.* FROM TableA WHERE     ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tt);
> ```

temporary table is session, so You could use it with same name independent for each session.

But if handle returned values in application - prevent table locks, because CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (and INSERT SELECT) - require lock table, with external code - it just 2 independent selects.

Comment: Thank you! But I mis-worded my question. I have updated it with what I wanted as a result (the matching rows from Table A). That is the part I cannot figure out. How to get the matching rows from multiple results of the first part.

Comment: Why would they need `LIMIT` in a siubquery for this problem?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - it normal case, when thousands (and many - more then 50% could use some categories ) products could use the same categories. In my vision it just more proper way - reduce number of rows on inner query, rather than - return all, than sort, but sure - this is not only one way